# Catch Exception in Futures

Tags: scala, apache-spark, concurrent.futures

I have a spark application wrote in scala using futures. So until yesterday, I didn't have any try/catch inside the future but I need to add. Before try/catch, any errors inside the future stopped the spark application and this is the behavior that I want, but after try/catch the application completes without any error.

This is my main object:

```
object TableProcessorWrapper extends SparkSessionWrapper {

  def main(args: Array[String]): List[Unit] = {

    implicit val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(new java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool(4))

    val dynamodb = DynamodbOperations()

    val tables = dynamodb.getTablesToProcess(args(0), "tabela")

    val processors = for {
      table <- tables
    } yield Future {
      TableProcessor(table).start(spark)
    }

    Await.result(Future.sequence(processors), Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

This is a part of the code inside the future:

```
class TableProcessor(
    fileReader: FileReader,
    tableProcessorConfig: TableProcessorConfig,
    transformers: Seq[BaseTransformer],
    anonymization: AnonymizationBase,
    schemaConverter: SchemaConverter,
    logAnalytics: LogAnalytics
) {

  def start(spark: SparkSession): Unit = {


try {

CODE HERE

} catch {
        case e: Exception =>
          logAnalyticsWithFiles.stopProcessing().failedProcessing().writeLog()
          throw new Exception(e)
      }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, lets decouple Spark from this question, as once you involve spark, your `CODE HERE` part becomes very much important in this question. And with Spark, your code is supposed to do most of your work at Spark's executor nodes so any Exceptions thrown there might not have any presence in your driver code.

So, lets forget Spark for now and lets focus on `handle Future exceptions` part.

Lets say you are calling a `doSomethingWithTable(table: YourTableType): Unit` method.

```scala
val processors = 
  for {
    table <- tables
  } yield Future {
    doSomethingWithTable(table)
  }

// or

val processors = tables.map(table => Future(doSomethingWithTable(table))
```

Now, your `processors` should be a `Seq[Future[Unit]]`. Each of these futures can fail/succeed independently of others. Now your can simply handle these failures by individually providing error handlers,

```scala
futures.foreach(_.recover(throwable => logException(throwable)))

def logException(throwable: Throwable): Unit = {}
```

And if you are only concerned about "stopping the Spark Application" then that should not have been impacted at all by your addition or removal of that try-catch. The thing is that `Future`'s are not only eagerly evaluated but they are also non-cancellable. So unless your JVM process exits, those will keep on running to finish. And since you are rethrowing the exception after catching it, your jvm process termination should staty as it was without try-catch.

Comment: @AluanHaddad `sys.exit` stops the running JVM.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Yes. Fixed that.